# Optimistic rollups and simple transactions

Tags: layer-2, rollups, arbitrum

My understanding is that in an optimistic rollup, all data from users authorizing a transaction is stored on L1. The computation itself corresponding to that transaction is executed on L2.

For simple transactions such as 10 users all sending tokens to a new address, how is an optimistic rollup able to scale Ethereum? My intuition is that the origin and destination addresses + token amounts + signatures is pretty much everything - there's not much additional computation to do. So it would appear that using an L2 doesn't gain much since all those details (addresses, amounts and signatures) from the senders still has to go onto L1.

What am I missing?